# Background image not appearing Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed an app and am in the final stages of testing. I have tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy Youth (Android 4.2.1) which is working fine, and the image below shows how it should be laid out:
[image: Samsung Image]

However, when I test it on a Motorola Defy (Android 2.2.1), it looks like this:

[image: Android image]

As you can see, the background image is not visible at all. Below is my XML layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx.xx.xx.xx.report_old_logo"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:id="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose Existing"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Choose_existing"
                android:layout_below="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Take Photo"
                android:id="@+id/btn_take_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Choose_existing"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Location_label"
                android:text="Location"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
                android:text="Additional Information"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Location_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Back"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send Email"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Send_email"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />




        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have the background image in my "mdmi", "hdpi", "xhdpi" and "xxhdpi" drawable folders, correctly named.

Can anybody see what is causing this problem, and what i need to do to fix it.

Comment: since ImageView have not android:src attribute, please add the code where you call setImageBitmap()

Comment: @Deuterium the Imageview is not being used in association with the background, it forms part of the functionality of the app (receives an image from the camera)

Comment: @Deuterium the background image is being set in the :android:background="@drawable/background"

Comment: @scb998 Can you please tell me your Image resolution which you are setting in background?

Comment: @Deuteriom: `ImageView have not android:src attribute` - **EPIC FAIL**... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src

Comment: @pratt the dpi resolution is 1536x2048.

Comment: @pratt Thanks for asking that question - id put the higher resolution image in the project than id meant to. putting a lower resolution image in solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @scb998 yup I knew it, no worries you solved it, that's grt, happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to set your background image via the java code, while the resources are stored in the res folder.
The function Ti.UI.createImageView() method will do it, with your width and height properly specified.Then you can add it to your layout.